# How to programmatically block/execute javascript blocks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Let's have a generic snippet of javascript code such as:

```
<!-- Google Analytics -->
<script async src='//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js'></script>
<script>
window.ga=window.ga||function(){(ga.q=ga.q||[]).push(arguments)};ga.l=+new Date;
ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
<!-- End Google Analytics -->
```

Is there a way to avoid that this script executes when page loads? And later activate it (via javascript) as if it were started from the beginning?

A solution would be to add type="text/plain" to `<script>` tags to stop the execution. To activate them later we could create an empty `<script type="text/javascript"></script>` and put the content of the modified script into it (for the script tag with src attribute, we could just create a `<script type="text/javascript" src="..."></script>` with the same src attribute of the modified one) and add it to the page.

But what I'm looking for is to get the same result w/o modifying the script itself, maybe including it (as it is) into another tag, or rather than converting it into a string and let it being inserted into the page with jQuery.parseHTML().

Any ideas? Any helps would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: can't you wrap it in a function ?

Comment: You could just download with ajax whenever you need to.

Comment: @Billy, wrapping it in a function will work, but I'm looking for a way that avoids to get into (and modify) the script tag contents.

Answer (score 2):

```
function runMeLater() {
   var script = document.createElement('script');
      script.setAttribute('src', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js');
      document.body.appendChild(script);

    window.ga=window.ga||function(){(ga.q=ga.q||[]).push(arguments)};ga.l=+new Date;
    ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', 'auto');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
}
```

Comment: This will work, but I'm looking for a way that avoids to get into (and modify) the script tag contents.

Comment: @mimmovele And i am looking for a way that avoids me having to work for a living. Meanwhile ...  good luck with your quest :)